# Is there a function in Python's Logging to just get the message and not the codes?

Tags: python, logging, teradata, pyodbc

I have a Python script that uses PYODBC to connect to a Teradata database and passes some SQL to it to perform an ETL. I have the logging formatted to a basicConfig and would like to pass the exception to it but I just want the message and not all of the codes associated with it.

```
try:
    to do something
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(e)
```

The exception is something like:

```
('HY000', '[HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-5628)Column WorkflowStatu not found in ADW_STUDIO_FSCSO_TABLES.BI_TP_And_Event_Base_Details. (-5628) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I want to format the exception to only give me the actual message instead of including all of the associated codes. So, the result would be:

```
'Column WorkflowStatu not found in ADW_STUDIO_FSCSO_TABLES.BI_TP_And_Event_Base_Details.'
```

Is there a way to format the exception? The only thing I found from researching all day was to try and convert the exception to a string and then do some replacing/substring/character index stuff that got really messy. There could also be exceptions that don't fit the pattern of this one.

Comment: I'd be surprised if nobody has yet created a regex capable of parsing the logged messages' formatting. Whatever is generating the messages, I would expect you could configure the verbosity, and if not, it's likely that someone else has already done the hard work.

Comment: None of that stuff you want to remove was added by `logging`. The code that raised the exception is responsible for all of that. `logging` can't help you remove it - `logging` knows how to log stuff, not how to parse pyodbc exception messages.

Comment: Register [a custom `Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects)? That said, it's likely going to be very custom, I'm guessing that log message is mostly the message from the exception itself, the prefixes being part of the message, not added by the logging machinery, so you'd probably have to add custom code to strip them back off heuristically.

Comment: Logging is not responsible for these codes and cannot help you remove them. You need to format the error message before logging it.

Comment: Been a long time, but as I recall the exception is an array. In theory at least, the error message you want (or close as you're going to get), will be a specific element in that array.  As others have said, you can do whatever you want with that in your calling code or exception handling code.